# How to Set `getSupportFragmentManager` in side Navigation Drawer click event - Android Material design

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

how can i set `getSupportFragmentManager` inside navigation drawer Recyclers view click event.

```
public class DrawerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerListAdapter.DrawerViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<info> data = Collections.emptyList();

    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public DrawerListAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        mFragmentManager = fm;
    }

    public DrawerListAdapter(Context contex, List<info> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = contex;
    }

    @Override
    public DrawerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_row, parent, false);
        DrawerViewHolder holder = new DrawerViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DrawerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        info current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    static class DrawerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

       // private ClickListener clickListener;

        public DrawerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
               title.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("RecyclerView", "onClick：" + getPosition());

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, Fragment_home.newInstance(),
                            Fragment_home.TAG).commit();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible to call it on the Context, but you shouldn't. Instead, implement an interface, and call back to the Activity to have it perform the Fragment Transaction.

Comment: Interface will be a good choice.

Comment: @mike-m can you help me with some code?

Comment: please refer to this, if it could solve your problem :)
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/33896782/4381591](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33896782/4381591)